# Localization text not showing at tab title

Tags: asp.net-mvc, frameworks

I can not change title of my tab from site.text.tr.json file. 
I add string below :

```
"StudentIn.StudentInGeneralDefinitions:StudentInformation": "Fatura Bilgileri",
```

My Tab Code:

```
 <div id="~_Tabs" class="s-DialogContent">
   <ul>
     <li>
       <a href="#~_TabStudent">
         <span> {{text:"StudentIn.StudentInGeneralDefinitions:StudentInformation"}}
         </span>
       </a>
     </li>
```

Comment: I know nothing of this framework, but based only on your code samples, I can already see that `StudentIn.StudentInGeneralDefinitions:InvoiceInformation` is not the same as `StudentIn.StudentInGeneralDefinitions:StudentInformation`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part below is a JsRender extension that runs at client side

`{{text:"StudentIn.StudentInGeneralDefinitions:StudentInformation"}}`

For this key to resolve its text representation, this localtext must be available client side. This means it should be transferred to client side from server side.

By default, Serenity only transfers a certain set of local texts to client side. This is to limit size of transferred texts and avoid revealing some sensitive strings to client code.

A web.config setting (LocalTextPackages) controls which texts are transferred (by default ones that starting with "Db.", "Site.", "Forms.", "Dialogs." etc.)

Either add StudentIn there, or use local text keys starting with "Site." for example:

"Site.StudentIn.StudentInGeneralDefinitions:StudentInformation"